# Make TypeScript Container with keys auto complete

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How do I make a Container of key value pairs that will allow include auto complete for keys?

**Example**

```js
class Container<T> {
....
}

const container = new Container<number>();

container.set('one', 1);
container.set('two', 2);
container.set('three', 3);

container.getAll().one // Auto-completion for 'one', 'two', 'three'
container.getAll().z // TypeScript error for accessing an undefined key
```

**Note:** the Container is just an example of a class I would like to create that will behave as mentioned

Also is there a way to get a union of keys from a Map constructor?

ex:

```js
type Containers = .... // 'One' | 'two' | 'three'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is a `new Container<number>()`?

Comment: @Behemoth just an example of a class I would like to create that will behave as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. However, this is impossible to do with TypeScript since Types are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) at runtime.

Comment: @Behemoth strange, there are ORMs that allow you to create a model like `user` and then use it like `db.user.insert({...})`. how is it done then?

Comment: Well, inserting values is not the problem. You can do that with your `.set()` method too. But there's no way to know what will be added to a list at compile time.

Comment: @Behemoth it means that there is no ability to get type of incoming item before compile without declaring a static union list? Prisma somehow does it but maybe it creates types or something behind the hood when executing generate.

Comment: [Prisma ORM](https://www.prisma.io/) generates code when running `generate` that is located in your node_modules. But once more, that is not the problem. Image you call `.getAll()` then `.set()` and again `.getAll()`. You might get different results each time because you are working with dynamic values. Now, for the type checking we need types that are computed based on what is stored in Container at the time of calling `.getAll()`. And that is not possible. Prisma can't do that either. It's as if you already knew what is in the database before even querying.

Comment: @Behemoth Oh I see, is it complex to make this kind of generator?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in TypeScript, and in fact in any other language known to me. At compilation all of your typings are deleted. You want to get type-inference for values that are added to the container at runtime. TypeScript cannot know what values are going to be added to the container at runtime, so no suggestion is possible here.

However you can achieve something similar like this:

**Note:** I strongly recommend **against** using such tricks and hacks in real projects. It's really not something you want to be in your code, cuz it's basically making TypeScript give you **wrong** suggestions that can and will differ from the real values that were stored into the container.
I am posting this only in experimental purposes :)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2A7ALmAlogpgJwDwBUAaaAaUwE8ZMAPZTRAExgmWwwHNoBeaLANxwA+aAG8AUNEnQADmz5g60FvGyYAXNABKmYCoa4ylYvmE8RAX2iQtOvQYoRjgsRKntMyABQBrChsMQAJQa+KKuUlKqyACu2IjQyAAWaBAAdMqqANq+5AC6ANzh0OYuERAeuLqILKTQNHSMzKwcgj5+pMTyICHBcEioGDgExAHQAD6kwuIREZ5JKenIKphWMNq62PqjEyROgdDZFLnc0F2FRRFRsfHzMNYIKOhYeESkDuOTRSVF7sgAgiAQJ5eus7AEnGEZpEPNcEsk0hlMF8xN8qjVoohgIknpgGCcsAB3PqPQZ4RDRAC2ACMhMCXAB6enQfDwaAUsC+OEpaAElTeaDkeDRJSJIUgPFgEAEsCUaBYp4CoXYaDpDyeVIa-bEKlgYDRcrQNAAMzEjLhK3lGGgVNUHJgSXoCXI0kwMAJaEB1pWIHgLDEaOQcuxgzxPAxlqwDCKqq8AHIwO5Y8QAEwAZkC0fKXgARFSGNmUwAGYsZ-3ByOpX4AoH7M24AC00ESOBWDsNiCNLcxK152G8jisjHNp0l0Vd0GzCcw2cHeNz+asqiswBikpA5Hbw4eA2eAGJETJsPAXdhkORUi5w+XcZWPNXgdA643m0u2xhO6pu9AGPBXbGUDyfLEJKSRCuwiTDl0Y4wJO7gzmAQ7zvBS4sB6ICbm2244tg+5LEusjHjgZ4XqaABUpESKR0AAKK0NgurIDAOQwBgdDYOUK5oEgToutARpHhSVhyv02GUfSYhnrxWGkgEuCwKYcB1LQ9BMMSO5DAh5DEO+ODMsIAD8zLQBoGLeIg8AEogDLkZR0AABItoqwrAAhCSuoGbYQNE7DuKhSAQGJ-r+YGOQaNJzyyZJmDwEaQY4gwCmxrGj5Mg2TaOZ53m+cgXHVIBfYuEAA)

[image]

```
class Container<T, Keys extends string = never> {
    private store: Record<Keys, T> = {} as Record<Keys, T>

    get(key: Keys): T {
        return this.store[key];
    }

    set<const K extends string>(key: K, val: T): Container<T, Keys | K> {
        (this.store as Record<Keys | K, T>) [key] = val;

        return this as Container<T, Keys | K>
    }

    getAll(): Record<Keys, T> {
        return this.store
    }
}

const unchained = new Container<number>()

// To make this work you should always chain your .set(...) , because if
// the chain breaks then types will be lost
const chained = unchained
    .set('age', 23)
    .set("bd", 2000)

chained.getAll() // <- here the inference works, and the values "age" and "bd" are actually in the Container#store property.

unchained.getAll() // <- here the inference does'nt work, although the values "age" and "bd" are still in the Container#store property.

/**
 * Extracts keys intersection type from a container
 */
type ContainerKeys<C> = C extends Container<any, infer T> ? T : unknown

/**
 * Here you can test the suggestions
 */
const key: ContainerKeys<typeof chained> = '' // <- here the suggestions work
```

A much better, clean, readable and maintainable way is to just predefined the keys that you are meant to use like this:

```
type Keys = 'age' | 'bd'

class Container<T> {
  private store: Record<Keys, T | undefined> = {} as Record<Keys, T | undefined>

  getAll(): Record<Keys, T | undefined> {...}

  set(key: Keys, val: T) {...}
}
```

Comment: Oh, thats really nice. I'm looking for a solution for a tiny library I'm developing, the issue is that I would like to give the developer an option to register additional containers outside of the library and still allow autocomplete somehow. Is there any suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: @Drenky Not enough details to suggest anything better but just using generics. That's a whole another question, so you'll have to post another one specifically about development of the library and provide with more details

Comment: Can't my account is restricted for asking additional questions. I'm planning to make a library that registers middlewares and exports a register function that will allow the developer to register additional middlewares / override the existing ones. Will it do the job or I should use something different?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it

```
// these infer types, extract the types I want by `infer` syntax
type InferContainersValue<TContainer extends Container<unknown>> = TContainer extends Container<infer T> ? T : never
type InferContainersName<TContainer extends Container<unknown>> = TContainer extends Container<any, infer T> ? T : never

class Container<TValue, TContainers extends string[] = []> {
  private containers = new Map()

  set<TKey extends string>(key: TKey, value: TValue) {
    // In here, I create a new instance from the class,
    // pass my new key type as generic and set the value

    const clone = new Container<TValue, [...TContainers, TKey]>()

    clone.containers = new Map(this.containers)
    clone.containers.set(key, value)

    return clone
  }

  getKeys(): InferContainersName<typeof this> {
    // code here
  }

  getValues(): InferContainersValue<typeof this>[] {
    // code here
  }
}

const container = new Container<number>()
  .set("id", 1)
  .set("age", 1)
  
const keys = container.getKeys() // ["id", "age"]
const values = container.getValues() // number[]
```

---

##### What is `infer`? (first 2 lines)

as per [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types)

> We just found ourselves using conditional types to apply constraints and then extract out types. This ends up being such a common operation that conditional types make it easier.
>
> Conditional types provide us with a way to infer from types we compare against in the true branch using the infer keyword.

we can think it of as destructuring. imagine we want to destructure an item from an array in js:

```js
const [item] = arr
```

in the types world, we can use `infer` to extract a type from another type:

```
type Arr = [string, number, boolean]

type Item = Arr extends [infer T] ? T : never

// Item === string
```

and in our code, I use this infer syntax to extract the generic type that we have passed to the class like so:

```
type InferContainersName<TContainer extends Container<unknown>> = TContainer extends Container<any, infer T> ? T : never
```

---

##### Why do I clone the class every time I want to set a value?

Well, before I answer that, you should know that the type system in typescript does not care about what is going on the code during runtime. so if we use this pattern, the type system will not work as expected:

```
const container = new Container().set("one", 1)

container.getKeys() // return type: ["one"]

container.set("two", 2)
container.getKeys() // return type: ["one"]
```

and this problem exists because the typescript CANNOT mutate another variable/object type. it can only assign a new object with a new value. Therefore, we have to recreate the class with new types and return it.
BUT, why don't I just return `this` and explicitly override the type? imagine this example:

```
const baseContainer = new Container<string>()
    .set("databaseUrl", "...")

const backendOneContainer = baseContainer
    .set("port", "3000")
const backendTwoContainer = baseContainer
    .set("port", "3001")
```

in this scenario, if we do NOT clone the instance and just return the `this`, there will be only 1 container instance that makes conflicts:

1. `baseContainer` which has only databaseUrl and port 3001

but if we clone the instance every time we set a new value, then in this scenario, there will be 3 instances:

1. `baseContainer` which has only databaseUrl
2. `backendOneContainer` which has databaseUrl and port 3000
3. `backendTwoContainer` which has databaseUrl and port 3001

---

feel free to ask questions if it is confusing for you or if you need to add more functionality to it

Comment: Is it possible to use it in production? The comment above you suggested not to use the code snippet in production.

Comment: I'm planning to make a library that registers middlewares and exports a register function that will allow the developer to register additional middlewares / override the existing ones. Will it do the job or I should use something different?

Comment: @Drenky the code snippet (the typescript type system world) does not work in production. but this is not important at all since we don't even need it. all you want here is to have an autocompletion to help you code faster and debug easier. if you want to use it in a library and let other developers extend the existing container, you just need to give an instance of this container class and other developers can simply use `set` method to add values. (if you also want to let them override existing key-values, you need to add more functionality to override the types based on your needs)

Comment: Can you maybe explain the two first lines and explain why do we need the clone?

Comment: @Drenky just updated the answer by answering your questions. sorry if it is confusing :) if you still did not understand, tell me and I will try better :)